# How To Get List Reduce To Throw Arithmetic Overflow

Tags: f#

So, yesterday while working through some F# code as part of a coding exercise, another developer pointed out something interesting. We were just doing a quick piece of code to demonstrate summing a list. If I do:

```
[1..100000] |> Seq.sum
```

I get the following error:

```
System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0003>.$FSI_0003.main@()
Stopped due to error
```

However, if I do:

```
[1..100000] |> List.reduce (+)
```

I get:

```
val it : int = 705082704
```

I realize although these two pieces of code should accomplish the same purpose they are very different. I am just curious is there a way to get the List.reduce to throw the OverflowException rather than giving me a bad answer?

Comment: Just an addition to existing answers: sum of `1..100000 = (100001 * 100000)/2 = 5000050000 = 0x12A06B550` which is an overflow. Dropping a overflow bit: `0x12A06B550 - 0x100000000 = 0x2A06B550 = 705082704`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a checked operator:

```
[1..100000] |> List.reduce (Checked.(+))
```

Answer (score 7):

From the f# source code

```
[<CompiledName("Sum")>]
let inline sum (source: seq< (^a) >) : ^a = 
  use e = source.GetEnumerator() 
  let mutable acc = LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero< (^a) >
  while e.MoveNext() do
      acc <- Checked.(+) acc e.Current
  acc
```

Notice the Checked.(operator) this checks for arithmetic overflows…

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee340296.aspx